# how to solve "stack space overflow" in haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, lazy-evaluation

Running the following program will print "space overflow: current size 8388608 bytes."  I have read [this](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Stack_overflow) and [this](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance/Accumulating_parameter), but still don't know how to resolve my problem.  I am using foldr, shouldn't it be guaranteed to be "tail recursive"?

I feel great about Haskell so far until I know I should prevent "space overflow" when using the powerful recursion. :)

```
module Main where
import Data.List

value a  b = 
  let l = length $ takeWhile (isPrime) $ map (\n->n^2 + a * n + b) [0..]
  in (l, a ,b)

euler27 = let tuple_list = [value a b | a <-[-999..999] , b <- [-999..999]]
      in foldr (\(n,a,b) (max,v) -> if n > max then (n , a * b) else (max ,v) ) (0,0) tuple_list
main = print euler27
```

EDIT: remove the definiton of `isPrime` for simplicity

Comment: It's the difficult with any functional language.  As a smart bloke I know once said every abstraction is leaky.  Functional languages are great for expressing yourself and showing an algorithm will complete correctly but they all have to assume that they have infinite memory.

Welcome to the world of fitting your beautiful program into a real computer...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As pierr answered, you should use `foldl'`. For more details:

- `foldl'` calculates its "left-side" before giving it to your fold step.
- `foldr` gives your fold step a "thunk" for the right-side value. This "thunk" will be calculated when needed.

Let's make a sum with `foldr` and see how it evaluates:

```
foldr (+) 0 [1..3]
1 + foldr (+) 0 [2..3]
1 + 2 + foldr (+) 0 [3]
1 + 2 + 3 + foldl (+) 0 [] -- this is a big thunk..
1 + 2 + 3 + 0
1 + 2 + 3
1 + 5
6
```

And with `foldl'`: (tag omitted in code because SO doesn't display it nicely)

```
foldl (+) 0 [1..3]
-- seq is a "strictness hint".
-- here it means that x is calculated before the foldl
x `seq` foldl (+) x [2..3] where x = 0+1
foldl (+) 1 [2..3]
x `seq` foldl (+) x [3] where x = 1+2
foldl (+) 3 [3]
x `seq` foldl (+) x [] where x = 3+3
foldl (+) 6 []
6
```

In good uses for `foldr`, which don't leak. the "step" must either:

- Return a result that doesn't depend on the "right-side", ignoring it or containing it in a lazy structure
- Return the right-side as is

Examples of good `foldr` usage:

```
-- in map, the step returns the structure head
-- without evaluating the "right-side"
map f = foldr ((:) . f) []

filter f =
  foldr step []
  where
    step x rest
      | f x = x : rest -- returns structure head
      | otherwise = rest -- returns right-side as is

any f =
  foldr step False
  where
    -- can use "step x rest = f x || rest". it is the same.
    -- version below used for verbosity
    step x rest
      | f x = True -- ignore right-side
      | otherwise = rest -- returns right-side as is
```

Comment: It seems that you should remove the `=` in the first line of `step`.

Answer (score 4):

replace

```
foldr (\(n,a,b) (max,v) -> if n > max then (n , a * b) else (max ,v) ) (0,0) tuple_list
```

with

```
foldl' (\(max ,v) (n,a,b) -> if n > max then (n , a * b) else (max ,v) ) (0,0) tuple_list
```

solved this problem, should that suggest we should always prefer to use foldl' instead of other variants(foldl,foldr)?