# Haskell thunks - foldl vs foldr

Tags: haskell

Learning Haskell, I came across the fact that `foldl` creates thunks and might crash the stack, so it's better to use `foldl'` from `Data.List`. Why is it just `foldl`, and not, for example, `foldr`?

Thanks

Comment: Is [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292212/how-to-solve-stack-space-overflow-in-haskell/1292853#1292853), especially the first few sentences, of any help?

Comment: Some Haskell wiki pages on folding: [Fold](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Fold) and [Foldr_Foldl_Foldl'](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl')

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no need for `foldr'` because you can cause the effect yourself.

Here is why: Consider `foldl f 0 [1,2,3]`. This expands to `f (f (f 0 1) 2) 3`, so by the time you get *anything* back to work with, thunks for `(f 0 1)` and `(f (f 0 1) 2)` have to be created. If you want to avoid this (by evaluating these subexpressions before continuing), you have to instruct `foldl` to do it for you – that is `foldl'`.

With `foldr`, things are different. What you get back from `foldr f 0 [1, 2, 3]` is `f 1 (foldr f 0 [2, 3])` (where the expression in parenthesis is a thunk). If you want to evaluate (parts of) the outer application of `f`, you can do that now, without a linear number of thunks being created first.

But in general, you are using `foldr` with lazy functions for `f` that can already do something (e.g. produce list constructors) before looking at the second argument.

Using `foldr` with a strict `f` (e.g. `(+)`) has the unwanted effect of putting all applications on the stack until the end of the list is reached; clearly not what you want, and not a situation where a however-looking `foldr'` could help.

Comment: One could foldl' the flipped f over the reversed list.

Comment: You mean if `f` is strict? Right, but reversing the list itself is not a “cheap operation” in a sense.